# Getting XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES when inserting documents from a for loop

Tags: json, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have built a REST endpoint that receives records from a single JSON file and inserts/updates each item as it's parsed.

```
{
  "records" : [
  {
    "description" : "test",
    "createDate" : "20181018 125816.220",      
    "owner" : "Smith, Bob",
    "uniqueID" : "REF-12-3456",      
    "status" : "Draft",
    "title" : "test record for Bob"
  },
  {
    "description" : "test 3",
    "createDate" : "20181018 125816.220",      
    "owner" : "Jones, Ben",
    "uniqueID" : "REF-12-7890",      
    "status" : "Draft",
    "title" : "test record for Ben"
  },
  {
    "description" : "test",
    "createDate" : "20181018 125816.220",      
    "owner" : "Smith, Bob",
    "uniqueID" : "REF-12-3456",      
    "status" : "Complete",
    "title" : "Completed test record for Bob"
  },
 ]
}
```

My endpoint sends the JSON to a function that parses each item creates a URI from the uniqueID field, sends each node to a function to add a metadata node and insert the document.

```
declare function local:doc-from-web($doc as document-node()*)
{
  let $message :=
    for $item in $doc/managementOfChange
     let $uri := $item/uniqueID
     let $loaded :=  local:load-doc($kms,$uri)
     return $loaded  
  return $message
};

declare function local:load-doc(
  $doc as object-node(),
  $uri as xs:string
)
{
  let $metadata := json:object()
  let $_ := map:put($metadata, "commonDate", $doc/createDate)
  let $_ := map:put($metadata, "commonStatus", $doc/status[1])        
  let $_ := map:put($metadata, "ingestDate", fn:current-dateTime())

  let $metadataJson := xdmp:to-json($metadata)

  let $object := json:object()
  let $_ :=  map:put($object,"RECORD",$doc)
  let $_ :=  map:put($object,"metadata", $metadataJson)

  let $newDoc := xdmp:to-json($object) 

  let $insert := xdmp:document-insert(
    $uri,
    $newDoc,
      ( xdmp:permission("rest-reader", "read"),
        xdmp:permission("rest-writer", "update") ),
      ("collection1","collection2")
  )

return “Document Inserted”
};
```

Because there can possibly be updated versions of the same record in the JSON load file (see nodes 1 and 3 in my sample data), and the for loop runs in a single transaction mode, this results in conflicting updates.

Is there a way to avoid this?  Is there a better way to process the data from the single file?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need each individual draft version or is it ok to just load the latest version of each document? Is the last version in your file always the latest? If yes, you could just loop from bottom to top, and skip all documents which are already processed by a more recent version. This way you could avoid updating the same document multiple times.

Comment: There is another way to perform this. Create group by query based on "uniqueID" field and perform logic to get most updated document before ingestion into the system.

Comment: another option depending on how many (and size) if docs,  make a map variable, indexed by uri, dont insert docs in your loop just load and/or update whats in the map (like  a cache)  then do a final loop over the map and insert the results.